# How to fetch data from Google Firestore into my Vue instance?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a game lobby where a player starts a game and waits for a second player to join.

When a second player joins, the document that carries the information about the game in Firestore, is updated and the player's name is stored in a playerJoined: property. And I receive it successfully:

```
waitForOtherPlayer(gameId){
            this.unsubscribe = fb.firestore().collection("active-games").doc(gameId+'').onSnapshot(function(doc) {
                if(doc.data()!== undefined) {
                    if(doc.data().playerJoined !== null && doc.data().playerJoined !== undefined) {
                        this.playerJoined = doc.data().playerJoined  // I have a global var called playerJoined
                        console.log('1st this.playerJoined: '+this.playerJoined)
                        this.isPlayerJoined = true
                        console.log(this)
                        console.log(typeof this)
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
                }
                return
            });
        },
```

All good! console.log() proves that the name of the other player is received. However I can't forward it to the global this Object.

This is the Vue Object:
[image]

And this is actually what "this" in the callback refers to:

[image]

I have no idea on how to return the data into the Vue object, so I can pass it to other methods and DOM and so on. I am literally all day experimenting with stuff, re-reading all the relevant Firestore docs, but apparently I am missing something and I need your help to find it

Answer (score 1):

> I am missing something

Why not using VueFire since you're doing with Vue + Firebase?

Links: https://vuefire.vuejs.org/